# Edit images with GraphicsMagick and save them directly to S3 using console or PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, graphicsmagick

I'm using GraphicsMagick to edit images uploaded by users. Each image is resized to several sizes.
First, I resize an image to the large size and save it to GraphicsMagick temporary MPC format for fast access during further operations:

```
gm convert uploaded.jpg -resize "640x800>" +profile "*" -unsharp 0x0.75+0.75+0.008 uniqueid.mpc
```

Then I convert uniqueid.mpc to several sizes and send them to S3 via aws-cli:

```
gm convert uniqueid.mpc -quality 90 640x.jpg
gm convert -size 400x400 uniqueid.mpc -resize "200x200^" -gravity Center -crop "200x200+0+0" -quality 90 -unsharp 1.5x1+0.7+0.02 200x.jpg
```

etc.

How can I skip creating temporary files 640x.jpg, 200x.jpg etc. and save results directly to S3? Command line is preferred, PHP and PHP extension GMagick can be used as alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

By replacing the target image name with a  `-` you can output the file to a pipe or capture the file into a variable.

```
gm convert uniqueid.mpc -quality 90 - | aws-storage-command
jpg640=`gm convert uniqueid.mpc -quality 90 -`
```

I would need to know your exact AWS command to tell you how to pipe this back to your command that moves the file to S3 as not all commands are conducive to direct file pipes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently I'm using aws from here: [link](http://www.timkay.com/aws/). Now I've tried: `gm convert 1.jpg - | aws put "Content-Type: image/jpg" BUCKET/1.jpg`, but the final image got spoiled colors :( Doesn't seem to be reliable. Such thing never happened when using temporary files.